Unable to see Resources, Metadata, Extensions and Dashboard in WSO2 carbon
I have installed WSO2 API Manager 4.3.0.
When logged into https://localhost:9443/carbon I am not able to see the below options.

Dashboard
Extensions
Metadata
Resources

All I can see is the screen below. What could be the problem ?
enter image description here
Tried re-install and still the same issue.

This behavior is expected as the team intentionally removed unused Carbon UI portals in WSO2 Carbon version 4.3.0. This removal aims to streamline the user interface and improve overall performance.
https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/pull/13449
